# Material based in mesh and not on verices

Tags: materials, node-editor, scale

I want to create a T-Shirt, that has this pattern on it, like shown in the picture, my problem is that I want to have the image texture based on the mesh, and not on the density of the vertex.

So that the pattern is evenly distributed. I have made a *UV Map* node connected to *Vector* from a *Mapping* node with a scale's factor on X and Y, which is connected to a *Image Texture*, connected to the material output.

I'm sorry, but i cant take a picture of it.

When I take a vertex and grab it on the Y axes, the image is also scaled in the Y-axis, so that my pattern is scaled on the Y-axis.

I don't want my pattern scaled, but increased in numbers, so that it fits.

Comment: Take a screenshot: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: I would, but my Computer has a problem with the Internet connection, and I only can post from my Smartphone. And I dont can send a screenshot to my smartphone from my computer, because my computer has a porblem with the internet connection..

Comment: And if i take a photo from my Computer, I cant upload it from my Phone

Comment: Finaly I have done it. I reposted my question with my computer under "material distributed based on mesh and not on vertex"